# SQL запрос по поставщикам

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте. Как составить запрос
"Определить количество поставщиков магазина с каждой страны. Результаты отсортируйте по странам по алфавиту"

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE postavschik ( 
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id'::regclass),
    nameofcompany character(40),
    country character(35),
    town character(30),
    zipcode character(10),
    address character(25),
    phone character(20),
    fax character(20),
    manager character(100),
    CONSTRAINT postavschik_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );

ALTER TABLE postavschik OWNER TO postgres;
```

Запрос

```
Select count(country) as "Количество", country as "Страна" from postavschik group by country;
```

Такой запрос находит количество с каждой страны, но не сортирует по алфавиту. Используя `order by country asc` выдает ошибку:

> ОШИБКА: колонка "postavschik.country" должна фигурировать в
>   предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции

Что-то недопонимаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.
СУБД: PostgreSQL

Comment: приведите текст ошибки, и структуру таблицы покажите

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь
"ОШИБКА: колонка "postavschik.country" должна фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции"
`CREATE TABLE postavschik
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id'::regclass),
  nameofcompany character(40),
  country character(35),
  town character(30),
  zipcode character(10),
  address character(25),
  phone character(20),
  fax character(20),
  manager character(100),
  CONSTRAINT postavschik_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE postavschik
  OWNER TO postgres;`

Comment: то есть получается либо там, либо там.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь как быть тогда?

Comment: вы, когда `order by` писали, `group by` не стерли?

Comment: @zRrr :DD, стер)) текст запроса c order by (выдающий ошибку)
`Select count(country) as "Количество", country as "Страна" from postavschik order by country asc;`

Comment: Верните обратно, вам же все еще надо сгруппировать по странам и подсчитать строки в каждой группе. Нельзя одновременно использовать агрегатные функции (`count`) и обычные поля, если обычные поля не указаны в `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY country ORDER BY country` означает, что вы группируете по полю `country`, а потом сортируете результат по нему же

Comment: @zRrr, оформите ответом, пожалуйста, ибо ваш комментарий им и является.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**: не указали какой SQL сервер. Проверил для MS SQL, MySQL - можно сортировать по номеру поля, не совсем удобно если потом в запросе добавятся дополнительные поля.

```
Select
    Count(country) as "Количество",
    Country as "Страна"
From postavschik
Group by country
Order by 2;
```

**Вариант 2**: с помощью вложенной таблицы

```
Select
    Kol as "Количество",
    country as "Страна"
From
    ( Select
          count(country) kol,
          country as "Страна"
      From postavschik
      Group by country ) R
Order by country;
```